# Memory leak on WPF/MVVM/PRISM - memory increased when window close and open again

Tags: wpf, memory, mvvm, prism

i have a big project and when it start up, it used ~100MB Ram and keep increasing over and over again when i open a window and close it, my app used more 30MB RAM and keep increase, i don't know how to fix this...
Please help me resolve this issue.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a memory profiler to determine what is maintaining a reference to the window. Then fix the bug. There are several such profilers available. I find [SciTech's memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/) to be excellent (no affiliation).